# Get dependencies on tables called from a DB thanks to a DBLINK in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, dependencies, dblink

I have a DB "myDB" in oracle with a DBLINK "MyDBLink" pointing on another oracle DB "MyOriginalDB". The connection is working. I created several tables and views in MyOriginalDB and I created views in "myDB" pointing on these one.

For instance my View "Users_V" (in myDB) calls the table Users_T from MyOriginalDB:

```
SELECT * FROM Users_T@MyDBLink
```

All is working.

I need now to retrieve all views and tables (all dependencies) in myDB calling the objects (tables and views) from MyOriginalDB thanks to the DBLINK.

I try this query:

```
SELECT
name, referenced_name, referenced_type, dependency_type
FROM user_dependencies
```

Nevertheless I don't get all calls to the different objects (of MyOriginalDB) from the views in myDB thanks to the DBLINK (@MyDBLink used in the queries of the views).

Could you help me to do that?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Perhaps you need to query DBA_DEPENDENCIES, which would give you all the dependencies at the database level, whereas USER_DEPENDENCIES will return only the objects which are accessible to your current user.

Comment: What is the problem? "but it's not complete for having the results that I want:" what does that mean ? What do you get from that query ?

Comment: I would like to have the different calls to the table or view yo the DBLINK as this call `SELECT * FROM Users_T@MyDBLink`. Here we can see  `@MyDBLink` in the query of the view. But I don't find a way (in one query) for retrieving all calls to this DBlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [oracle documemtation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D74F9AD4-387A-4773-8C40-337F4152645F.htm#REFRN23053):

> DBA_DEPENDENCIES describes all dependencies in the database between
>   procedures, packages, functions, package bodies, and triggers,
>   including dependencies on views created without any database links.

So it is not possible to find dependancies on view if it is created using `db links`.
You must use `*_views` to find the text of the views and find your db link within text of the view.

Cheers!!

Comment: `*_views` ? Could you tell me how to use that ?

Comment: `select * from all_views` or `user_views` and where condition should include finding the db link name from `text` column